# Sync Gradle projects with workspace failed: Execution failed for task

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

I am trying to import a fresh project into my eclipse photon workspace with JAVA 8 and Gradle 4.8.1. I see the following exception. I am not sure why it is trying to build tests while importing the project itself.

```
org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Could not run build action using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.8.1-all.zip'.
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ExceptionTransformer.transform(ExceptionTransformer.java:51)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ExceptionTransformer.transform(ExceptionTransformer.java:29)
    ...
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: Execution failed for task ':buildSrc:test'.
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultExceptionAnalyser.transform(DefaultExceptionAnalyser.java:74)
    at org.gradle.initialization.MultipleBuildFailuresExceptionAnalyser.transform(MultipleBuildFailuresExceptionAnalyser.java:47)
    ...
Caused by: org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':buildSrc:test'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:77)
    ...
    ... 3 more
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: There were failing tests. See the report at: file:///C:/sources/elasticsearch-master/buildSrc/build-bootstrap/reports/tests/test/index.html
    at org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.AbstractTestTask.handleTestFailures(AbstractTestTask.java:612)
    at org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.AbstractTestTask.executeTests(AbstractTestTask.java:484)
    at org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.executeTests(Test.java:603)
    ...
    ... 30 more
```

**UPDATE**
Both didn't work however am using 4.4.1 version now :

"Loading Gradle project preview faileddue to error in the referenced gradle build"

```
org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Could not fetch model of type 'GradleBuild' using Gradle installation 'C:\gradle'.
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ExceptionTransformer.transform(ExceptionTransformer.java:51)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ExceptionTransformer.transform(ExceptionTransformer.java:29)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ResultHandlerAdapter.onFailure(ResultHandlerAdapter.java:41)
    ...
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: Execution failed for task ':buildSrc:compileGroovy'.
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultExceptionAnalyser.transform(DefaultExceptionAnalyser.java:74)
    at org.gradle.initialization.MultipleBuildFailuresExceptionAnalyser.transform(MultipleBuildFailuresExceptionAnalyser.java:47)
    ...
Caused by: org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':buildSrc:compileGroovy'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
    ...
    ... 95 more
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.ApiGroovyCompiler.execute(ApiGroovyCompiler.java:180)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.ApiGroovyCompiler.execute(ApiGroovyCompiler.java:56)
    ...
    ... 3 more
```

Comment: I guess because the latest supported gradle version is `gradle-4.4-all.zip`

Comment: Stop auto build and import.